# Cut a circumference into parts - Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path

I'm trying to cut out sections of a circle / circumference.

The way that I've been doing it is by creating new nodes on the path and then cutting the path at that point. However, to make the cuts I then have to drag the circle freehand and it moves out of shape. How can I get around that?

Ideally, what I'm looking for is a circle with vertical cuts in it. Then I want to put shapes in the gaps, [like so](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax7g17iej2u2qw3/GG_plasmid.svg):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a circle.
2. *Convert Object to Path*.

   [image]
3. *Extensions → Modify Path → Add Nodes…* Select *by number of segments.* In the example I chose five segments; you will likely want to choose a higher number.

   [image]
4. Create a symmetric trapezium.

   [image]
5. Select the trapezium and your circle and apply *Extensions → Modify Path → Perspective.*

   [image]
6. Remove trapezium.
7. In the *Nodes* tool, your circle should look like this (note how the nodes are not placed equidistantly):

   [image]
8. Duplicate the circle an appropriate number of times.
9. Move one duplicate upwards.
10. Select all duplicates and use some vertical distribution tool from the alignment tools, e.g., *Distribute centres equidistantly vertically.*

    [image]
11. Remove unneeded duplicates.
12. Use *Path → Combine* on the remaining ones.

    [image]
13. Remove some segments by selecting the appropriate nodes and using *Delete segment between two non-endpoint nodes.*

    [image]
14. Add some segments by selecting the appropriate nodes and using *Join selected endnotes with a new segment.*

    [image]
15. Repeat as desired.

    [image]
16. Use *Path → Break Apart.*
17. Remove spurios path segments.

    [image]

You can replace steps 4 to 6 by just distorting the circle to an ellipsis, but I assumed that the above is closer to what you desire. Also, you can get a more accurate perspective by placing step 8 before step 4 and applying steps 4 to 6 seperately to every circle (with different trapeziums).

Comment: Oh wow that's an amazing answer - that's the perfect way to do it. Thanks! I had managed to do it by creating a circle and then inserting and nodes and cutting the path manually. This has shown me that if you stay really logical with inkscape you can get a perfectly accurate result.

Comment: If I wanted to add text on the side of the shape, curving around it like writing on the edge of a coin, how would I do that?

Comment: @Okoning: Use *Put Text on Path.* (If that is not sufficient, please ask a new question.)